# Android Notification Sound Not Ringing From Internal Memory

Tags: android, notifications, audio

**History:**
I download Ringtone from web server, if SD card is mounted i saved that file to SD Card path like, mnt/sdcard/.my_folder_name/abc.mp3 ELSE saved to internal memory using context.getFilesDir() like, data/data/my.package.name/abc.mp3

**PROBLEM:**
I'm firing Android Notification in Notification Bar, Notification is working fine but the problem occurs when i set NOTIFICATION SOUND URI from internal memory, it Doesn't play sound.

**IN CASE OF EXTERNAL STORAGE, WORKS FINE and SOUNDS PLAYS**

```
ringtoneUri = Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/.my_folder_name/abc.mp3");

notification.sound = ringtoneUri;         

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notification.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;

notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

**IN CASE OF INTERNAL STORAGE, DOESn't Play SOUNDS PLAYS** i checked the file, it exists there

```
ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(context.getFilesDir().getPath()+"/abc.mp3");
```

*// data/data/my.package.name/files/abc.mp3*

```
notification.sound = ringtoneUri;         

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

notification.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;

notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

**Am i Doing something Wrong???**

Regards,

Comment: No Answer?? :( its urgent...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, Internal Storage is not supported to Use by NOTIFICATIONS.
You need to add public permission to that Audio File.

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath()+"/abc.mp3");
file.setReadable(true, false);
ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(context.getFilesDir().getPath()+"/abc.mp3");
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.audioStreamType = AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

...
Thanks
Salik

Answer (score 0):

I would check permissions. Each application is a user. Do all users have the right to read the file (and probably the enclosing folder[s])?

Comment: Like what permissions?

Comment: If i play by using Media Player library it allows me to play from data/data folder

Comment: File permissions, like `adb shell ls -l /mnt/sdcard/` shows you.

Comment: Permission denied to me.. but whats the solution?

Comment: Set the permissions, [File.setReadable()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadable(boolean,%20boolean))

Comment: doesn't solve. Okay please tell me, Is i am correct, I am saving Notification Mp3 file to data/data/my.package.name ???